# What is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verb-agreement

Which of these two is  correct?I assume that only one of them is correct.

1. How is John, Sally and Kevin
2. How are John, Sally and Kevin

Comment: Sorry forgot to add a question mark at the end of both the sentences

Comment: You can edit the question directly.

Comment: Everything is  correct  in English.It is flexible  and  there are no strict  rules.It is  waste of  time  asking  for  correctness

Comment: What @JVL said is just patently not true.

Comment: @J.A Teroba.What you say is correct.Sometimes I get vexed when  the answer which isconsidered wrong is found to be correct.It is a fact that  English is very flexible

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct. The fragment "John, Sally and Kevin" is the subject, which is a collection of people, therefore making the subject a plural.

Comment: if you are addressing Sally and Kevin by name, asking after the wellbeing of John, then the first is correct as well.